# ImportError: cannot import name 'base' from 'jqmcvi' (unknown location)

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I get this error when I try the below code

```
from jqmcvi import base
```

And I have imported the package jqmcvi from [the github repository](https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi) using below command

```
git clone https://github.com/jqmviegas/jqm_cvi jqmcvi
```

How can I `import base` from `jqmcvi`?

I am using Kaggle.

Comment: Merely cloning a package doesn't install it.

Comment: The `!` command looks like you are using Jupyter or something; probably spell this out in the question, too.

Comment: Going forward, please [edit] the question; information in comments tends to get lost.

Comment: Merely running `git clone` only places the files on your disk; it does nothing to inform Python that a new module is available.

If the project is well-structured, you would `pip install` from the Github link *instead of* cloning it; but how exactly to do this on your system depends on a number of factors.